# Who chooses what order to apply damage prevention and redirection effects in a fight?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Swans of Bryn Argoll](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwans%20of%20Bryn%20Argoll%5d) is involved in a fight and an opponent activates an ability to redirect damage assigned to the Swans of Bryn Argoll.  Which effect takes precedence?  My assumption is that the controller would chose which damage prevention mechanism to use.

Answer (score 6):

When multiple damage redirection and prevention effects, or other replacement effects, are applied to the same object for the same event, the controller of the object decides the order in which they are applied. In this case, the controller of the Swans of Bryn Argoll decides whether the damage is redirected or the damage source's controller draws the cards. The exact process for applying these effects is described in the rules section titled [Interaction of Replacement and/or Prevention Effects](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Interaction_of_replacement_and/or_prevention_effects).

Comment: Note that the Swan's controller doesn't draw the cards; the damage source's controller does.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that part of the effect. I fixed the description in the answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? That player would decide on the order their effects are applied certainly, but they are applied in APNAP order otherwise. If I had swans, and my opponent had an effect that was redirecting/preventing damage, it would depend who's turn it is which was actually applied.

Comment: That is true of triggered abilities and many other effects, but as you can see from the rules section I linked, replacement and prevention effects work differently. The controller/owner of the thing that events are happening to (Swans, in this case) decides the order of all events.